# Override Currency for a Locale

Tags: java, spring

On our project, we get currency whith java.util.Currency for each country. The problem is that a country will change its currency to EUR and we will need a new Java release that contains this change the same day. Is there a way to cutomize the currency of a Locale on the launching of JVM ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The locale (note lower case) is ultimately the responsibility of the OS and its sysadmins keeping it up to date (including Java updates). The only way to ensure with certainty that EUR were used is if you get the app to poll some server controlled by you checking for updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. We can override currencies by adding a properties file named currency.properties on <JAVA_HOME>/lib.

#Sample currency properties

JP=JPZ,999,0